# How to remove the dash for multiple files in linux

Tags: linux, bash, filenames

I'm having files named like `HCW-00109-01.sam`

I want to change the name of them into `HCW0010901.sam`

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful with the rename command.  It could overwrite files if you do not use the `-o`.  And of course, if you mess up, there is no undo.

- The `-a` says to do the replacement multiple times
- The `-o` says no overwriting files
- `--` means treat the rest of the command as arguments and not options
- replace dash with empty string for all files that have a dash in it

  ```
  rename -a -o  -- '-' '' *-*
  ```